# Como transpor linhas para colunas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Já foi respondido pelo Motta, obrigado pela paciência.**

Como posso transpor linhas para colunas no SQLServer, para que algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fique com este formato?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Camarada, deixe mais clara a sua pergunta, explique o que você precisa, pois não dá para entender o que você realmente quer

Comment: Já procurou sobre pivot table? seria isso q vc quer?

Comment: João, coloque na sua pergunta que você quer saber como transformar o resultado da consulta que está em colunas em linhas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com UNION talvez

```
select 'jan' , jan linhabase from tabela 
union
select 'fev' , fev linhabase from tabela 
union
...
select 'dez' , dezlinhabase from tabela
```

Mas o problema me ficou pouco claro , outra coisa é o que me parace um modelo ruim.

Pesquise também por UNPIVOT

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado Motta!

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma um pouco mais elegante do que foi apresentado, seria usar `unpivot`,

```
select *
from Tabela
unpivot
(
  Valor
  for Ano in ([Jan], [Fev], [Mar], [Abr], [Mai], [Jun], [Jul], [Dez]) unpiv
order by ano desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer contar os valores. Use o `SUM` Exemplo..

```
SELECT sum(Jan), count(Fev), sum(Mar),..... FROM tabela.
```

Resultado será a a soma das linhas nas colunas em Janeiro, fevereiro, etc...

Comment: Não contar, é pq peguei de uma tabela fake a segunda imagem, mas é pra passar os valores de linha pra coluna, ao invés de 12 linhas fazer 2 colunas, uma pro mes e outra pros valores dos meses

Comment: Como disse o cavalheiro em cima, especifique melhor sua pergunta.